# C# Toast Notification in Action Center, but greyed out

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications, toast

I am making a WPF Application that shows a Toast Notification and afterwards displays it in the Action Center. Therefore I included the references to the Win 10 Library. I also created a Shortcut to the startmenu and assigned a AppModelUserID to the Application and the same to the Toast.

Till now everything works just fine, and the banner appears on the screen, but when it's showed in the action center, it's greyed out and I can't activate it. As Toast on the screen, it can be activated.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give us some code, otherwise it's like fishing in the dark.